# How do you send messages from Flask server (Python) to HTML client?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask, websocket, send

For practice, I'm trying to get the Flask server to constantly print "Hello" to the HTML page's console. I'm currently lost with how to proceed.

Currently, my **server code** looks something like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
 socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
 def handle_message(message):
    print('Message: ' + message)
     send(message)

@socketio.on('json')
 def handle_json(json):
    send(json, json=True)

@socketio.on('my event')
  def handle_my_custom_event(json):
     emit('my response', json, broadcast=True)

def hello():
    emit('message', {'hello':"Hello"})

@app.route('/')
 def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     socketio.run(app)
     while True:
          hello()
```

While my **client code** looks like this:

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                 socket.emit('connected');
            });
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
            });
      </script>
</head>
```

But I'm not getting anything in my console log for the page. How do I get it to print the message sent from the Flask server to the console? What am I doing wrong?

I understand right now, it should print the JSON instead of the "Hello" string, and that's ok too. I just want something to print on the web console from the server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how to connect to the SocketIO server and receive a message from the server upon that connection.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template                                        
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit                                       

app = Flask(__name__)                                                           
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'                                            
socketio = SocketIO(app)                                                        


@socketio.on('connect')                                                         
def connect():                                                                  
    emit('message', {'hello': "Hello"})                                         


@app.route('/')                                                                 
def index():                                                                    
    return render_template('index.html')                                        


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<head>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                 console.log('connected');
            });
            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
            });
      </script>
</head>
```

**Edit:**

To have the server send a socketio message every five seconds, you can use a background thread:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template                                        
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit                                       
import time                                                                     

app = Flask(__name__)                                                           
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'                                            
socketio = SocketIO(app)                                                        
thread = None                                                                   


def background_thread():                                                        
    while True:                                                                 
        socketio.emit('message', {'goodbye': "Goodbye"})                        
        time.sleep(5)                                                           


@socketio.on('connect')                                                         
def connect():                                                                  
    global thread                                                               
    if thread is None:                                                          
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=background_thread)       


@app.route('/')                                                                 
def index():                                                                    
    return render_template('index.html')        


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Comment: Awesome!! How do I get it to periodically send messages though (say every 5 seconds)?

Comment: Usually you would only have the server send a message to connected clients on some event occurring. It doesn't really make sense for the server to just continuously send the same message. But if you really wanted to go down this path you might be able to start a background thread which emits a socketio message every five seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you mind providing an example of that as well (I found an example online, and tried it, and couldn't get it to work)?

Comment: For some reason, the second example isn't working. Python output is stuck at "(7134) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(7134) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 63548)" and web console says "ET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lhztt_G net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. The example works on my machine so it could be something specific to your setup/platform.

Comment: I had to add "import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()" for some reason, and it worked! Thanks so much for your help!